# (Catalina) Is there a progress status when updating iPhone?

Tags: macos, iphone, software-update, catalina

In the new Catalina MacOS iPhone interface (from the Finder).

Is there a way to see the progress (numerical or percentage) of the iPhone update download and update?

Currently, there's only a spinning indicator next to the iPhone entry in the Finder.

Comment: I noticed that in many previous versions of iTunes as well, sigh...

Answer (score 6):

Try to run this command in the terminal to check for the file being downloaded.

```
ls -lah ~/Library/iTunes/iPhone\ Software\ Updates
```

My Results show the following while im trying to update my iphone to IOS 13.2.2

```
drwxr-xr-x@ 3 username  staff    96B Nov 15 20:55 .
drwxr-xr-x@ 4 username  staff   128B Apr 28  2019 ..
-rw-r--r--  1 username  staff   1.2G Nov 15 21:52 iPhone_5.5_P3_13.2.2_17B102_Restore.ipsw.download
```

The file being downloaded is the one containing the "13.2.2" in its name with a current size of 1.2 GBs, although this will not show you how much is left, but it will show that there is progress.

IOS(13.2.2) size is 4185242982 bytes(3.9 GBs)